# Dompdf max-height max-width supported or not?

Tags: php, css, dompdf

I am trying to restrict images to a certain height and width as a maximum. So naturally I am using max-height and max-width so the images can stay in their aspect ratios when they hit their max. Works in html, here is my code snippets

```
'<table class="seperate" id="images-table">'.   
        '<tbody>'.
          '<tr>'.
            '<td>&nbsp;</td>'.
            '<td class="uscs-logo" ><img src="http://localhost/dompdfTest/dompdf/uscompliancesystems_logo.png" /></td>'.

            '<td class="signature-logo" ><img src="http://localhost/dompdfTest/dompdf/USCSDefaultSignature.jpg" /></td>'.
            '<td>&nbsp;</td>'.
          '</tr>'.
        '</tbody>'.
    '</table>'.
```

And the css:

```
table#images-table .uscs-logo {
  height: 100px;
  text-align: left;

}

table#images-table .uscs-logo img{
    max-height:200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
table#images-table .signature {
  height: 125px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  max-height:200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

But what I get in the pdf is a two page pdf with no images on the page because they are coming in at full size. If I render in html to the page, it comes out fine.

So my question is, is max-width and max-height really supported with dompdf on img tag?

Comment: Just for info PHPpdf seems support this : https://github.com/psliwa/PHPPdf#attributes

Comment: You should be able to specify the max width/height of an image in the current version of dompdf, but not other elements. Which version are you using?

Comment: toto21 - we are not looking to use a different pdf generator.
BrianS - I downloaded the most recent version a few weeks ago, 5.5.3

Comment: Most recent version of dompdf? Should be 0.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that difficult to resize images on the fly with the GD PHP Extension.  As far as time cost, the Browser has to scale if you don't.

```
$filename ='/home/user/public_html/images/image.jpg';
$image = @imagecreatefromjpeg();
$originalWidth  = imagesx($image);
$originalHeight = imagesy($image);
$scale      = min($desiredWidth/$originalWidth, $desiredHeight/$originalHeight);
$newWidth  = ceil($scale*$originalWidth);
$newHeight = ceil($scale*$originalHeight);
$newPic = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($newPic, $image,0, 0, 0, 0,$newWidth, $newHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
if (imagejpeg($newPic,$tmpfile)){rename($tmpfile,$filename);}
```

And restore memory cleanup.

```
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($newPic);
```

Comment: I was mostly posting to get more information specifically about DomPdf and to see why the max-width and max-height do not work. But this is an interesting solution.

Comment: It is considered a poor practice to have the Browser do the scaling.The why is probably the developers did either did not not anticipate having to scale images, of they thought the user should be using images that are properly scaled.    But for whatever reason it does not work you need some sort of work around.  My solution is for when in a production environment the images often need to be scaled.  If this is a one shot deal then using a stand alone image utility would be easier.   For that situation I find the free Fast Stone Image Viewer to be a very capable image tool.

Comment: We are resizing the image using php first. Still would like an answer to why documentation says max-width and max-height are supported, but don't work in the pdf for DomPdf.

Comment: max- may be supported but may not be 100% supported for images.  Possibly if you had made the image as a div with the images as its background.  domPDF is intolerant of HTML errors.  Your `<img>` tags do not have height or with specified.  That is a big problem for rendering.  Rendering's first paint uses the the width and height  for the rough layout.  After the HTML and CSS is rendered, then the images are retrieved.  The image dimensions are retrieved and  the layout must be adjusted.  Not an ideal situation.   You should pose the question in the domPDF forum.

Comment: One thing to note about resized images is that a larger image placed in a smaller space in the PDF will result in a higher relative DPI for the image and thus potentially better quality on print. Or at least it should. The most recent version of dompdf does a lot of image processing which could result in some loss of quality.